# Limit on constructor

Tags: java

```
public class Office {
private char building;
private int floor;
private int roomnumber;}

public class Employee {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String mail;
private String phone;
private Office office;}
```

I am making a Office in Java and have to restrict only one office per employee, meaning that every instance of a Office can only be used by one Employee. The Office is made by the Office Class and is included in the Employee Class. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What is the problem with the existing code?

Comment: I am currently able to add the same office to several different employees. I want to put a maximum limit of 1 on how many employees can use the same office.

Comment: If that's the case you should add `Employee` as property on the `Office` class and remove `Office` on the `Employee` class

Comment: By same office you mean same combination of `building`, `floor` and `roomnumber`?

Comment: Could use error checking to sequence through all the employees and make sure that none have the same office right after you get into the Office constructor.

Comment: user2004685: Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

1. Create a `Set<String>` and start putting objects with `building_floor_roomnumber` as Key.
2. Before initializing the Office check if `building_floor_roomnumber` already exists in the Set.

Here is a small snippet to demonstrate it:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    /* You can also make it global; depending on your needs */
    Set<String> office = new HashSet<>();
    String key = "A12-London_F6_R121";

    if(office.contains(key)) {
        System.out.println("Already Taken!");
    } else {
        office.add(key);

        /* Create New Office Object & Initialize it */
        Office off = new Office();
        off.setBuilding("A12-London");
        off.setFloor("F6");
        off.setRoom("R121");

        /* Set it back to Employee Object */
        /* I'm assuming you have some Employee Object named emp */
        emp.setOffice(off);

        System.out.println("Added Successfully!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to implement `.equals` and `.hashCode` on the `Office` class. With this solution you are maintaining `Office` logic at 2 places.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you but, how would you compare any office object with all other office objects already assigned to the respective employees?

Comment: Instead of using `Set<String>` it will become `Set<Office>`, you have to fill the office object before the if statement. The advantage is, that if the requirements of an unique `Office` changes, you have to maintain it in the `Office` class and not in ditributed places.

Comment: Okay. So suppose I have changed `Set<String>` to `Set<Office>` and I have filled the first `Office` object say *of1* with the above values and added it to the Set. Next, I created a new instance of `Office` say *of2* and filled it with exact same values as before. Now, if I'll try to add this new object *of2* to my Set then it should say `Already Taken!`. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out how to do it with your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you only want one Office object to be created, you need to do the following:
You can have a static class variable of type boolean, that you will change to true once the first instance is made. When a new instance is being made, you will check if this boolean is true and if it is, you may throw an exception ect.

Example:

```
private static boolean hasBeenInstanciated = false;

public Constructor(){
    if(hasBeenInstanciated){
        throw new IllegalStateException("This class has already been instanciated once!");
    }else hasBeenInstanciated = true;
//The rest of your constructor code goes here.
}
```